# How can i get apps on my phone from ONLY my other phone, and not my tablet?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, sony-xperia-tipo

I am going to get a replacement phone and i only want apps from my old phone to be downloaded to the new one, and not my tablets apps. i know there is "google play-my apps-all", but that includes my tablets apps too. they are all on the same account. (the reason for this is my phone has very little storage and i dont want my tablets 3GB apps taking up my phone.) my phones are both on android 4.0.4 (sony xperia tipo) (ICS). i do not want to root but i will download any app (no apks please, sorry). **thanks in advance!! :D**

Answer (score 1):

Use [the Helium app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup) to backup your phone and then do a restore on the new one.

I am not affiliated with developers of Helium in any way, only a regular user.

Helium is just a (sophisticated) frontend to adb backup, so if you feel adventurous, you can achieve similar results using just adb.

Answer (score 0):

What if u change the account on the tablet first, then try to transfer apps from old phone? Not certain ofd that will work, but It should. If Apple can do it android can.